# Returning unique elements from values in a dictionary

Tags: python

I have a dictionary like this :

```
d = {'v03':["elem_A","elem_B","elem_C"],'v02':["elem_A","elem_D","elem_C"],'v01':["elem_A","elem_E"]}
```

How would you return a new dictionary with the elements that are not contained in the key of the highest value ? 
In this case :

```
d2 = {'v02':['elem_D'],'v01':["elem_E"]}
```

Thank  you,

Comment: You should tell us what you have tried till now. Hint: look up `filter` and the `not in` conditions and give it a try.

Comment: What does **key of the highest value** mean please ? Is it on the basis of sorting all the keys, these ones being all strings ??

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to do differences with the builtin data type designed for it: sets.

It is also preferable to write loops rather than elaborate comprehensions. One-liners are clever, but understandable code that you can return to and understand is even better.

```
d = {'v03':["elem_A","elem_B","elem_C"],'v02':["elem_A","elem_D","elem_C"],'v01':["elem_A","elem_E"]}

last = None
d2 = {}
for key in sorted(d.keys()):
    if last:
        if set(d[last]) - set(d[key]):
            d2[last] = sorted(set(d[last]) - set(d[key]))
    last = key

print d2
{'v01': ['elem_E'], 'v02': ['elem_D']}
```

Comment: Using set operations is an elegant way to achieve the desired. The procedural approach allows for very fast execution. However, I disagree on the incentive of choosing procedural loops over list/dict comprehension for the sake of understandability. When it comes to readability, I use comprehensions wherever possible performance drawbacks seems justifiable, because of the compactness and liberty in expression coming with them. Especially when formatted into multiple lines, comprehensions can be easier to read than equivalent loop constructs. It probably comes down to personal preference. [+1]

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict
myNewDict = defaultdict(list)
all_keys = d.keys()
all_keys.sort()
max_value = all_keys[-1]
for key in d:
    if key != max_value:
        for value in d[key]:
            if value not in d[max_value]:
                myNewDict[key].append(value)
```

You can get fancier with set operations by taking the set difference between the values in d[max_value] and each of the other keys but first I think you should get comfortable working with dictionaries and lists.

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'v01': ['elem_E'], 'v02': ['elem_D']})
```

one reason not to use sets is that the solution does not generalize enough because sets can only have hashable objects.  If your values are lists of lists the members (sublists) are not hashable so you can't use a set operation

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your python version, you may be able to get this done with only one line, using [dict comprehension](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):

```
>>> d2 = {k:[v for v in values if not v in d.get(max(d.keys()))] for k, values in d.items()}
>>> d2
{'v01': ['elem_E'], 'v02': ['elem_D'], 'v03': []}
```

This puts together a copy of dict `d` with containing lists being stripped off all items stored at the max key. The resulting dict looks more or less like what you are going for.
If you don't want the empty list at key `v03`, wrap the result itself in another dict:

```
>>> {k:v for k,v in d2.items() if len(v) > 0}
{'v01': ['elem_E'], 'v02': ['elem_D']}
```

***EDIT:*** 
In case your original dict has a very large keyset [*or said operation is required frequently*], you might also want to substitute the expression `d.get(max(d.keys()))` by some previously assigned list variable for performance [*<strike>but I ain't sure if it doesn't in fact get pre-computed anyway</strike>*]. **This speeds up the** whole thing by almost 100%. The following runs 100,000 times in 1.5 secs on my machine, whereas the unsubstituted expression takes more than 3 seconds.

```
>>> bl = d.get(max(d.keys()))
>>> d2 = {k:v for k,v in {k:[v for v in values if not v in bl] for k, values in d.items()}.items() if len(v) > 0}
```